# Downvote comment

Tags: feature-request, comments, voting

I'm aware it is not possible to downvote comments at the time, but I guess this would be a useful feature. Just like questions/answers, comments can be constructive, helpful or on the contrary, confusing or worse, wrong. Would such a feature be implemented sometime?

**EDIT**: Another argument in favor is that comments can be edited only for a limited time, so after a while no corrections can be made.

Comment: I guess this can be tagged {[meta-tag:status-declined]}?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This has already been discussed on the main meta site:

- [Should downvoting be allowed on comments?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3615/should-downvoting-be-allowed-on-comments)

and it has been declined. The same also for cancelling upvotes on comments:

- [Should I be able to cancel my up-vote on a comment?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1170/should-i-be-able-to-cancel-my-up-vote-on-a-comment)

Comment: I guess the first link is an answer. Thanks! `:)`